# Is every Genshin Daily special Commissions equaly probable?

Tags: genshin-impact

This is just a random idea that came to mind after seeing multiple Youtube players rants about never getting specific commissions.

Every day the game gives the player 4 different commissions (normally all located in the same region unless something overrides that). Most of the time the first commission is a special one given by an NPC while the remaining three are "normal" fight monster ones.

Some of these commissions cause permanent changes in the world. "Miracle Medicine" ends up with Anna cured, "Urgent Repairs" fixes the staircase at the inn and so on. Obviously they are not repeatable after the final step is completed. Those are also the ones most people want to get, with Miracle Medicine being probably the most sought after.

Yet multiple players rant about never getting Miracle Cure even if they started playing when the game launched **a year ago**. The thing became even more blatant recently after the last patch introduced the ability to choose a region for the commissions, thus theoretically reducing the odds of wasting a day on commissions from unwanted areas.

The question is therefore simple: did anyone manage to prove if the special commissions are supposed to be all equally probable or some commissions are indeed much rarer to get?

The wiki currently contains the following notices about commissions.

> On Daily Reset (4:00 AM, server time), players will receive four commissions (0-2 NPC commissions and 2-4 basic commissions) from the Adventurers' Guild, viewable from the Quest menu or the Adventurer Handbook. Commissions are randomly assigned based on the preferred region set in the Adventurer Handbook, or if set to random, from a randomly selected region that the player has unlocked. However, emergency quests outside of the preferred region (including certain NPC follow-up quests) may still appear. Additionally, some commissions are only added to the pool of potential commissions upon completing the prerequisite quest or commission. Due to the random nature of commissions and the daily limit of possible NPC commissions, it may take many months for a specific NPC commission to appear.

But nothing is said about every commission having the same odds to appear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 4.4 updated added a new feature that rendered this question de-facto obsolete: now achievement related quests are given an higher priority and can even repeat back-to-back until the player completes said achievement.

> If related achievements of a Commission Quest are not unlocked yet, the probability of that Commission Quest appearing will increase.

(source: [Official HoyoLab post](https://www.hoyolab.com/article/24727988))

This has the potential to even become 100% if there is a single achievement missing commission under certain circumstances (mostly notable if the player hasn't yet unlocked the other commissions in Inazuma and is therefore only missing the achievement from The Taste of Home in the default pool) causing the same quest to be selected **every day** until the player finally caves in and gets the achievement.

Obviously this also has the potential to backfire horrendously should the game decide that the player **MUST** get one of the "You are an horrible person" achievements like killing the pigeons in Timmie quest, locking the player from doing other quests because they refuse to perform some bad actions.